# SQL Calculate Sale Closure Percentage Rate Per Sales Person For Regions A and B

Tags: sql

I have a dataset (sales_dataset) where each row represents a sales attempt, and there are 3 columns showing the sales person (sales_person), region (region), and whether the attempt was successful or not (sale). The table can be seen here:

[image: dataset]

I am trying to calculate the percentage of successful sales grouped by each sales person for regions A and B but I can't seem to figure out how to do so i.e. I am trying to find (successful sales / total sales) for each sales_person for regions A and B. You can see an image of what I am trying to generate here:

[image: goal]

The furthest I've gotten so far is to generate a count of succesful sales for each sales person, with the following query:

```
SELECT sales_person, Count(sale) as "Sales Rate %"
FROM sales_dataset
Where sale = "Sale" AND region = "A" OR "B"
Group By sales_person
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `avg()`:

```
select sales_person,
       avg(case when sale = 'Sale' then 1.0 else 0 end) as sales_rate
from sales_dataset
where region in ('A', 'B')
group by sales_person;
```

Comment: Thank you so much; was stuck on that for hours!